# Sort today's habits by priority in main agenda view

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to sort today's habits by priority in the main agenda view. I haven't yet found a way to do it. Here is what I've got in my custom.el (everything else is how I want it but the priority-down doesn't seem to work on habits the way I expect: A's before B's before C's):

```
 '(org-agenda-sorting-strategy
   (quote
    ((agenda time-up habit-up priority-down category-keep)
     (todo priority-down category-keep)
     (tags priority-down category-keep)
     (search category-keep))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out org-habit-get-priority is called by org-agenda-get-scheduled in org-agenda.el. I copy org-agenda-get-scheduled and override it with a small change:

```
        'priority (+ 94 (- 5 diff) (org-get-priority txt)) ;; (if habitp
            ;;   (org-habit-get-priority habitp)
            ;; (+ 94 (- 5 diff) (org-get-priority txt)))
```

and voilá. It would be nice if org-habit-get-priority was a pluggable function that we could provide and if we didn't, it'd use the default as provided.

Comment: One the Emacs SE I created an alternative solution that doesn't require editing the org-mode source code: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32430/how-to-sort-habits-by-priority-in-the-org-agenda-view

Comment: Thanks @holocronweaver. Good to know.